# Why the conversion of EditText to String was not suceesful within OnCreate method

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText number1, number2;
    String number_1, number_2;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        number1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number1);
        number2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number2);
        number_1 = number1.getText().toString();
        number_2 = number2.getText().toString();
```

After running the application, why does `number_1` have an empty value.

Comment: onCreate() is called when the Activity is created..at that time there is no text is set to the EditText thats why its returning empty String..For this you need to take a button and write listener and get the values..

Comment: What are you *expecting* to see?

Comment: and you can get a valid text in `onCreate()` if you used `android:text="some_text"` attribute for `EditText` in xml layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onCreate method is create view.
So EditText number1, nubmer2 is not create yet.
If you want get number1 or number2's value, try in onPause().

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

You have to get the text in like `OnClick` while starting application both EditText is empty. So that it returns empty.

```
number_1 = number1.getText().toString();
number_2 = number2.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have predefined the value in the edittext and that should work

Answer (score 0):

You need to fill the EditTexts with something before you can get their value. So create a button, and **after** filling the EditTexts, *then* get their values by clicking the button.

Perhaps like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

EditText number1, number2;
String number_1, number_2;
Button submit;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    number1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number1);
    number2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number2);
    submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1); //Define a button in your layout xml file with the ID field set as "btn1"

   submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
    number_1 = number1.getText().toString();
    number_2 = number2.getText().toString();
}
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

i need to see your xml.... if your trying to get numbers you have to parse the string to an int anyway... what are you trying to achieve? you simply want the text, from each of the textviews? is there text set in the xml?

Answer (score 0):

```
Make sure you have predefined the value in the edittext in xml file.
like in your layout file android:text="your string" or else you have to set string after binding
oncreate method like.
        number1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number1);
        number2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number2);
         number1.setText("your string");

    then you have to get string from below code.

        number_1 = number1.getText().toString();
        number_2 = number2.getText().toString();
```